# OpenVPN: Push a route to client with a different gateway

Tags: routing, openvpn

I would like my OpenVPN server to push a route down to the client with a different default gateway.

Specifically, my OpenVPN server has an internal IP address of `10.0.0.1`, and I would like it to push a route of `10.10.10.1/24` using gateway `10.0.0.2`.

Is it possible to do this by specifying a push route in the server config file?

Comment: Are you saying you want to `push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0"` to the client, and then the VPN clients traffic to have a different default gateway (10.0.0.2) on the VPN server network?

Comment: @DravSloan I want the client to access IP addresses on the 10.10.10.0/24 network via 10.0.0.2, but I don't want to change any of the other routing behavior of the VPN.

Comment: @josten I tried doing: `push "route 10.10.10.1/24 255.255.255.255 10.0.0.2"`, no go.

Comment: @LorinHochstein that should probably be `push route "10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2 1"`

Comment: @josten Do you want post that answer, seeing as you suggested it (I just filled in the blanks...)

Comment: @DravSloan I think you've given him enough time and ought to go ahead and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2 1"
```

From the OpenVPN man page:

```
--route network/IP [netmask] [gateway] [metric]
```

This tells the server config to "push" to the client, the `route` command which sets a networking route of the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet via the gateway 10.0.0.2 with a metric of 1. Metrics are used to give "preference" if multiple routes exist (such that the lowest cost wins).

Comment: `push route "10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2 1"` made the openvpn parser crash. Had to specify `push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2 1"` instead.