# Client route for OpenVPN Access Server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn

I am running OpenVPN Access Server and I'd like to push a route to every client on connection that is the equivalent of:

```
sudo ip route add 172.17.0.0/24 via 172.27.232.1
```

Where should I go to set this up (preferably in the OpenVPN AS Web UI)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the following to your server's `openvpn.conf` file:

```
push "route 172.17.0.0 255.255.255.0 172.27.232.1"
```

the restart things.

The default config file has a similar line commented out with a `;` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you would simply add the following to your /etc/openvpn/server.conf:

```
push "route 172.17.0.0 255.255.255.0 172.27.232.1 1"
```

The configuration is described in more [detail here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117775/101059).

But, to answer question about making the change through the OpenVPN AS WebUI, I think you will have use the "Yes, using routing (advanced)" option shown [in this document](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides-sp-859543150/howto-administration/215-how-to-setup-routing-in-openvpn-access-server.html) and then make further configuration.  As the document notes, the machines you have on the `172.17.0.0/24` subnet will have to have a route back to the VPN clients, otherwise they will send that traffic back to their default gateway.